# Loop to hide sheets

Tags: vba, excel

Currently, I am using this VBA code to hide all sheets in my spreadsheet:

```
Sub HideSheets()
    Sheet1.Visible = False
    Sheet2.Visible = False
    Sheet3.Visible = False
    Sheet4.Visible = True
End Sub
```

This code runs perfectly.

However, since I have more than just 4 sheets in my original file I would like to have a solution with a loop. Therefore, I tried to go with the following formula:

```
Sub LoopHideSheets()
    Dim b As Worksheet
    For Each b In Worksheets
        b.Select
        ActiveWindow.Visible = False
    Next b
End Sub
```

Once I run this code my Excel file crashes. I guess the reason for this is that at least one file needs to stay visible. Do you know what I have to change my loop code so all sheets getting hidden instead of `Sheet4`?

Comment: Replace the 2 lines within your `For Each` loop with `If b.Name <> "Sheet4" Then b.Visible = False`

Comment: Because you're trying to hide ALL the sheets, leaving nothing displayed. Excel will be much happier if you leave at least one sheet visible.

Comment: use for instead of for each and use a counter

Comment: @Peh: Thanks for the code. I put it in my code and it works. The only issue I have is that I would prefer to use the internal sheet name in the VBA object catalogue instead of the sheet name given by the user. Therefore, I tried to use b.worksheets <> Sheet4 then b.Visible but I could not make it work. Do you have any idea to solve this?

Comment: @Michi use `b.CodeName` instead of `b.Name`.

Comment: Thanks, works perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub LoopHideSheets()
    Dim b As Worksheet
    For Each b In Worksheets
        If b.Name <> "DontHide" Then    'whatever the sheet name is to not hide
            b.Visible = False
        End If
    Next b
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Davesexcel, your code works very nice. The only issue I still have is that instead of a sheet name (in your case "DontHide") I always use the internal sheet name as reference, therefore, I would like to put Sheet1 instead of the name of the sheet. However, so far I could not make it work using the internal sheet name.

Comment: Use `b.CodeName` instead of `b.Name` to check the VBA internal name instead of the public sheet name on the tab bar.

Comment: @Peh: Other question regarding the formats in your comment. How do you get the gray code format? I tried to use Ctrl+K as I do in my question but could not make it work.

Comment: Use the key below the esc key.. or above the tab key

Answer (score 1):

This will hide every sheet that is not named "Sheet4" - but be careful, you need to ensure Sheet4 exists or you will get an error.

```
Sub LoopHideSheets()

Dim b As Worksheet

For Each b In Worksheets
    If b.Name <> "Sheet4" Then b.Visible = False
Next b

End Sub
```

You might want to hide all sheets other than the one currently active..?

```
    If b.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then b.Visible = False
```

However, you may need to hide all but 1 (hey, I've no idea why) as per other answers. To do this properly, you need to count visible sheets and only deal with those:

```
Sub LoopHideSheets()

Dim b As Worksheet, shtcnt As Long

'Count up all visible sheets
For Each b In Worksheets
    If b.Visible = True Then shtcnt = shtcnt + 1
Next b

'Hide each visible sheet until only 1 is left
For Each b In Worksheets
    If b.Visible = True And shtcnt > 1 Then
    shtcnt = shtcnt - 1
    b.Visible = False
    End If
Next b

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can catch the error with error handling

```
Sub HideAllSheets()
    Dim b As Worksheet
    For Each b In Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next 'disable error reporting
        b.Visible = False
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
            MsgBox "The last sheet must stay visible" 'remove if you don't want a message
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0 're-enable error handling. Don't forget this line!
    Next b
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If You always want to have last sheet visible you could use this

```
Sub HideSheets()

Dim i As Long

With ThisWorkbook
    For i = 1 To .Sheets.Count - 1
        .Sheets(i).Visible = False
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This will fail if the last sheet is already hidden (eg by a previous code or manually) **before** you start this procedure.

Comment: True. Adding `.Sheets(.Sheets.Count).Visible = True` just before loop should help.